# How to repair a serialized string which has been corrupted by an incorrect byte count length?

Tags: php, mysql, serialization, content-management-system

I am using Hotaru CMS with the Image Upload plugin, I get this error if I try to attach an image to a post, otherwise there is no error:

> unserialize() [function.unserialize]: Error at offset

The offending code (error points to line with **):

```
/**
     * Retrieve submission step data
     *
     * @param $key - empty when setting
     * @return bool
     */
    public function loadSubmitData($h, $key = '')
    {
        // delete everything in this table older than 30 minutes:
        $this->deleteTempData($h->db);

        if (!$key) { return false; }

        $cleanKey = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]+/','',$key);
        if (strcmp($key,$cleanKey) != 0) {
            return false;
        } else {
            $sql = "SELECT tempdata_value FROM " . TABLE_TEMPDATA . " WHERE tempdata_key = %s ORDER BY tempdata_updatedts DESC LIMIT 1";
            $submitted_data = $h->db->get_var($h->db->prepare($sql, $key));
            **if ($submitted_data) { return unserialize($submitted_data); } else { return false; }** 
        }
    }
```

Data from the table, notice the end bit has the image info, I am not an expert in PHP so I was wondering what you guys/gals might think?

tempdata_value:

```
a:10:{s:16:"submit_editorial";b:0;s:15:"submit_orig_url";s:13:"www.bbc.co.uk";s:12:"submit_title";s:14:"No title found";s:14:"submit_content";s:12:"dnfsdkfjdfdf";s:15:"submit_category";i:2;s:11:"submit_tags";s:3:"bbc";s:9:"submit_id";b:0;s:16:"submit_subscribe";i:0;s:15:"submit_comments";s:4:"open";s:5:"image";s:19:"C:fakepath100.jpg";}
```

Edit: I think I've found the serialize bit...

```
/**
     * Save submission step data
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function saveSubmitData($h)
    {
        // delete everything in this table older than 30 minutes:
        $this->deleteTempData($h->db);

        $sid = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]+/i', '', session_id());
        $key = md5(microtime() . $sid . rand());
        $sql = "INSERT INTO " . TABLE_TEMPDATA . " (tempdata_key, tempdata_value, tempdata_updateby) VALUES (%s,%s, %d)";
        $h->db->query($h->db->prepare($sql, $key, serialize($h->vars['submitted_data']), $h->currentUser->id));
        return $key;
    }
```

Comment: For me the quick fix for this was using base64_encode / decode before serialize / unserialize. http://davidwalsh.name/php-serialize-unserialize-issues

Comment: i dont know why but mine solved with added @, `@unserialize($product->des_txtmopscol);`

Comment: @BhavinRana adding `@` is not error resolving, it is error silencing -- nothing actually "gets fixed" with that technique.

Answer (score 239, accepted):

`unserialize() [function.unserialize]: Error at offset` was dues to `invalid serialization data` due to invalid length

**Quick Fix**

What you can do is is `recalculating the length` of the elements in serialized array

**You current serialized data**

```
$data = 'a:10:{s:16:"submit_editorial";b:0;s:15:"submit_orig_url";s:13:"www.bbc.co.uk";s:12:"submit_title";s:14:"No title found";s:14:"submit_content";s:12:"dnfsdkfjdfdf";s:15:"submit_category";i:2;s:11:"submit_tags";s:3:"bbc";s:9:"submit_id";b:0;s:16:"submit_subscribe";i:0;s:15:"submit_comments";s:4:"open";s:5:"image";s:19:"C:fakepath100.jpg";}';
```

**Example without recalculation**

```
var_dump(unserialize($data));
```

Output

```
Notice: unserialize() [function.unserialize]: Error at offset 337 of 338 bytes
```

**Recalculating**

```
$data = preg_replace('!s:(\d+):"(.*?)";!e', "'s:'.strlen('$2').':\"$2\";'", $data);
var_dump(unserialize($data));
```

Output

```
array
  'submit_editorial' => boolean false
  'submit_orig_url' => string 'www.bbc.co.uk' (length=13)
  'submit_title' => string 'No title found' (length=14)
  'submit_content' => string 'dnfsdkfjdfdf' (length=12)
  'submit_category' => int 2
  'submit_tags' => string 'bbc' (length=3)
  'submit_id' => boolean false
  'submit_subscribe' => int 0
  'submit_comments' => string 'open' (length=4)
  'image' => string 'C:fakepath100.jpg' (length=17)
```

**Recommendation** .. I

Instead of using this kind of quick fix ... i"ll advice you update the question with

- How you are serializing your data
- How you are Saving it ..

**================================   EDIT 1  ===============================**

**The Error**

The Error was generated because of use of double quote `"` instead single quote `'` that is why `C:\fakepath\100.png` was converted to `C:fakepath100.jpg`

**To fix the error**

You need to change `$h->vars['submitted_data']` From  (Note the singe quite `'` )

Replace

```
 $h->vars['submitted_data']['image'] = "C:\fakepath\100.png" ;
```

With

```
 $h->vars['submitted_data']['image'] = 'C:\fakepath\100.png' ;
```

**Additional Filter**

You can also add this simple filter before you call serialize

```
function satitize(&$value, $key)
{
    $value = addslashes($value);
}

array_walk($h->vars['submitted_data'], "satitize");
```

If you have UTF Characters you can also run

```
 $h->vars['submitted_data'] = array_map("utf8_encode",$h->vars['submitted_data']);
```

**How to detect the problem in future serialized data**

```
  findSerializeError ( $data1 ) ;
```

Output

```
Diffrence 9 != 7
    -> ORD number 57 != 55
    -> Line Number = 315
    -> Section Data1  = pen";s:5:"image";s:19:"C:fakepath100.jpg
    -> Section Data2  = pen";s:5:"image";s:17:"C:fakepath100.jpg
                                            ^------- The Error (Element Length)
```

`findSerializeError` Function

```
function findSerializeError($data1) {
    echo "<pre>";
    $data2 = preg_replace ( '!s:(\d+):"(.*?)";!e', "'s:'.strlen('$2').':\"$2\";'",$data1 );
    $max = (strlen ( $data1 ) > strlen ( $data2 )) ? strlen ( $data1 ) : strlen ( $data2 );

    echo $data1 . PHP_EOL;
    echo $data2 . PHP_EOL;

    for($i = 0; $i < $max; $i ++) {

        if (@$data1 {$i} !== @$data2 {$i}) {

            echo "Diffrence ", @$data1 {$i}, " != ", @$data2 {$i}, PHP_EOL;
            echo "\t-> ORD number ", ord ( @$data1 {$i} ), " != ", ord ( @$data2 {$i} ), PHP_EOL;
            echo "\t-> Line Number = $i" . PHP_EOL;

            $start = ($i - 20);
            $start = ($start < 0) ? 0 : $start;
            $length = 40;

            $point = $max - $i;
            if ($point < 20) {
                $rlength = 1;
                $rpoint = - $point;
            } else {
                $rpoint = $length - 20;
                $rlength = 1;
            }

            echo "\t-> Section Data1  = ", substr_replace ( substr ( $data1, $start, $length ), "<b style=\"color:green\">{$data1 {$i}}</b>", $rpoint, $rlength ), PHP_EOL;
            echo "\t-> Section Data2  = ", substr_replace ( substr ( $data2, $start, $length ), "<b style=\"color:red\">{$data2 {$i}}</b>", $rpoint, $rlength ), PHP_EOL;
        }

    }

}
```

**A better way to save to Database**

```
$toDatabse = base64_encode(serialize($data));  // Save to database
$fromDatabase = unserialize(base64_decode($data)); //Getting Save Format
```

Comment: Baba, I used your amazing `findSerializeError` function and found a lots of errors. Please take a look at [my topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19469068/unserialize-function-unserialize-error-at-offset-65530-of-65535-bytes)

Comment: use `base64` on Article before adding it to the database ... it would preserve the null character

Comment: thanks! I used base64_encode\base64_decode thing and it worked. But now I get the same error with different data and it's not working even with base64_encode\base64_decode thing in place. What does your function do?

Comment: What does your function do? I've created a [topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19477115/what-does-findserializeerror-function-do) to investigate that.

Comment: That is so not a better way to save to the database. It is, unless you want to completely neglect the purpose of the database. How are you going to perform a search in a bunch of encrypted values? Not to mention the bloat, ugh. Proper encoding is the proper answer.

Comment: If using PHP 5.5, see @r00tAcc3ss answer! http://stackoverflow.com/a/21389439/1003020

Comment: If you get this error " preg_replace(): The /e modifier is no longer supported, use preg_replace_callback instead" in php7 - this answer works https://stackoverflow.com/a/21389439/2011434

Comment: Man, you saved my day! If someone from Czech Republic will be searching that - used for Mioweb Wordpress serialized DB fields! Don't know how some companies can still exist when selling code like this...

Answer (score 108):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, so I hope this is seen by people using the above "correct" answer:

Since php 5.5 the /e modifier in preg_replace() has been deprecated completely and the preg_match above will error out. The php documentation recommends using preg_match_callback in its place.

Please find the following solution as an alternative to the above proposed preg_match.

```
$fixed_data = preg_replace_callback ( '!s:(\d+):"(.*?)";!', function($match) {      
    return ($match[1] == strlen($match[2])) ? $match[0] : 's:' . strlen($match[2]) . ':"' . $match[2] . '";';
},$bad_data );
```

Comment: This seems like the only only answer on the page that actually puts the first capture group to good use.  While sensible programming to only make replacements where the byte count is _actually_ wrong, this solution does not cache the `strlen()` and therefore makes redundant function calls.  Personally, I find the addition of an inline condition to be too verbose, but this snippet is doing good things for good reasons.

Comment: It worked for me with the following regex `'!s:(\d+):"(.*?)";!s'` (with an ending 's' to take new lines as well). Thanks to adilbo's comment below.

Comment: For me it failed on some complex serialized objects, so I used rexeg `'#s:(\d+):"(.*?)";(?=\\}*(?:[aOsidbN][:;]|\\z))#s'`

Comment: Thanks! It used in a PHP7+ project and worked

Comment: Sanya_Zol's regex worked for me, it is a complex data comprised of cyrillic text and HTML, thank you Sanya!

Answer (score 19):

**Quick Fix**

Recalculating the length of the elements in serialized array - but don't use (preg_replace) it's deprecated - better use preg_replace_callback:

**Edit: New Version now not just wrong length but it also fix line-breaks and count correct characters with aczent (thanks to [mickmackusa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2943403/mickmackusa))**

```
// New Version
$data = preg_replace_callback('!s:\d+:"(.*?)";!s', 
    function($m) {
        return "s:" . strlen($m[1]) . ':"'.$m[1].'";'; 
    }, $data
);
```

Comment: How does this incorrect solution have 8 upvotes? I shutter to think how many people would have unwittingly copy pasted this one-liner.  [sad face]  Here is proof of two ways in which this snippet will fail: https://3v4l.org/Cf6Nh  See my refined pattern and custom replacement @ https://stackoverflow.com/a/55074706/2943403

Comment: My solution is no longer at the other page because it was an incorrect solution for the catastrophically damaged serialized string.  I've added my snippet to this page and provided explanation and demonstrations.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/55566407/2943403

Answer (score 16):

There's another reason `unserialize()` failed because you improperly put serialized data into the database see [Official Explanation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) here. Since `serialize()` returns binary data and php variables don't care encoding methods, so that putting it into TEXT, VARCHAR() will cause this error.

Solution: store serialized data into BLOB in your table.

Comment: This solved my problem in Laravel 5. I changed the column definition from string() to binary().

Comment: The OP's question does not appear to have a mysql column type issue.  It is apparently corrupted by an incorrect byte calculation  on the `image` value.  Your answer does not pertain to the OP's specific question.  You may wish to move your advice to: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5544749/2943403

Answer (score 10):

```
$badData = 'a:2:{i:0;s:16:"as:45:"d";
Is \n";i:1;s:19:"as:45:"d";
Is \r\n";}';
```

**You can not fix a broken serialize string using the proposed regexes:**

```
$data = preg_replace('!s:(\d+):"(.*?)";!e', "'s:'.strlen('$2').':\"$2\";'", $badData);
var_dump(@unserialize($data)); // Output: bool(false)

// or

$data = preg_replace_callback(
    '/s:(\d+):"(.*?)";/',
    function($m){
        return 's:' . strlen($m[2]) . ':"' . $m[2] . '";';
    },
    $badData
);
var_dump(@unserialize($data)); // Output: bool(false)
```

**You can fix broken serialize string using following regex:**

```
$data = preg_replace_callback(
    '/(?<=^|\{|;)s:(\d+):\"(.*?)\";(?=[asbdiO]\:\d|N;|\}|$)/s',
    function($m){
        return 's:' . strlen($m[2]) . ':"' . $m[2] . '";';
    },
    $badData
);

var_dump(@unserialize($data));
```

Output

```
array(2) {
  [0] =>
  string(17) "as:45:"d";
Is \n"
  [1] =>
  string(19) "as:45:"d";
Is \r\n"
}
```

or

```
array(2) {
  [0] =>
  string(16) "as:45:"d";
Is \n"
  [1] =>
  string(18) "as:45:"d";
Is \r\n"
}
```

Comment: @mickmackusa Thanks. Fixed a problem with multibyte encodings.

Answer (score 6):

This error is caused because your charset is wrong.

Set charset after open tag:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

And set charset utf8 in your database :

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

Comment: I don't see any indication in the OP's posted question to suggest that the corruption is due to the charset.  Fee free to defend your claim, but as far as I can tell, someone has manually updated the `image` value and failed to update the byte count.  Unless informed otherwise, I have to assume that this answer is incorrect for the OP's question.

Answer (score 5):

```
public function unserializeKeySkills($string) {
    $output = array();
    $string = trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ',$string));
    $string = preg_replace_callback('!s:(\d+):"(.*?)";!', function($m) { return 's:'.strlen($m[2]).':"'.$m[2].'";'; }, utf8_encode( trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ',$string)) ));
    try {
        $output =  unserialize($string);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        \Log::error("unserialize Data : " .print_r($string,true));
    }
    return $output;
}
```

Comment: php unserialize

Comment: This solution is not suitable for many cases.  It makes the assumption that everyone will want to mutation the values in the serialized string to convert 2-or-more whitespace characters to a literal space AND `trim()` every matched substring. **That point alone makes this solution impossible to recommend.** Furthermore, it will choke on newline characters and unnecessarily captures the pre-existing byte count which is just going to be overwritten anyhow.  Finally, this is a "code-only answer" and these types of answers are low-value since they do little to educate/empower future researchers.

Answer (score 3):

the [official docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) says it should return false and set E_NOTICE

but since you got error then the error reporting is set to be triggered by E_NOTICE

here is a fix to allow you detect false returned by `unserialize`

```
$old_err=error_reporting(); 
error_reporting($old_err & ~E_NOTICE);
$object = unserialize($serialized_data);
error_reporting($old_err);
```

you might want to consider use base64 encode/decode

```
$string=base64_encode(serialize($obj));
unserialize(base64_decode($string));
```

Comment: `base64_encode` did the trick for me. Im my case we're passing `serialize`d data over the command line and it looked like some strange characters were preventing it from working correctly.

Comment: `base64_encode()` is not the solution to the question asked by the OP. The OP's question/issue is specifically dealing with the fact that (likely do to an inappropriate substring replacement on the "final array element" of the serialized string) there is an incorrect byte count in the serialized string. Please only post answers that directly deal with the question asked.

Answer (score 3):

You can fix broken serialize string using following function, with **multibyte character** handling.

```
function repairSerializeString($value)
{

    $regex = '/s:([0-9]+):"(.*?)"/';

    return preg_replace_callback(
        $regex, function($match) {
            return "s:".mb_strlen($match[2]).":\"".$match[2]."\""; 
        },
        $value
    );
}
```

Comment: The core of what this answer is recommending is simply wrong and will potentially damage perfectly valid serialized strings.  This snippet should not be used/trusted.

Comment: @mickmackusa I'm not getting your point, Can you please suggest best way to do it? or suggest edit on this answer..

Comment: I have provided a correct solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55566407/2943403 and explained that `mb_strlen()` is inappropriate because `serialize()` stores the byte count, not the character count.  Editing your answer to be correct would only create redundant advice on the page.

Answer (score 3):

The corruption in this question is isolated to a single substring at the end of the serialized string with was probably manually replaced by someone who lazily wanted to update the `image` filename.  This fact will be apparent in my demonstration link below using the OP's posted data -- in short, `C:fakepath100.jpg` does not have a length of `19`, it should be `17`.

Since the serialized string corruption is limited to an incorrect byte/character count number, the following will do a fine job of updating the corrupted string with the correct byte count value.

### The following regex based replacement will only be effective in remedying byte counts, nothing more.

It looks like many of the earlier posts are just copy-pasting a regex pattern from someone else.  **There is no reason to capture the potentially corrupted byte count number if it isn't going to be used in the replacement.**  Also, adding the `s` pattern modifier is a reasonable inclusion in case a string value contains newlines/line returns.

*For those that are not aware of the treatment of multibyte characters with serializing, you **must not use `mb_strlen()` in the custom callback because it is the byte count that is stored not the character count**, see my output...

Code: ([Demo with OP's data](https://3v4l.org/DA7IY)) ([Demo with arbitrary sample data](https://3v4l.org/R3MgC)) ([Demo with condition replacing](https://3v4l.org/FsZv1))

```
$corrupted = <<<STRING
a:4:{i:0;s:3:"three";i:1;s:5:"five";i:2;s:2:"newline1
newline2";i:3;s:6:"garçon";}
STRING;

$repaired = preg_replace_callback(
        '/s:\d+:"(.*?)";/s',
        //  ^^^- matched/consumed but not captured because not used in replacement
        function ($m) {
            return "s:" . strlen($m[1]) . ":\"{$m[1]}\";";
        },
        $corrupted
    );

echo $corrupted , "\n" , $repaired;
echo "\n---\n";
var_export(unserialize($repaired));
```

Output:

```
a:4:{i:0;s:3:"three";i:1;s:5:"five";i:2;s:2:"newline1
Newline2";i:3;s:6:"garçon";}
a:4:{i:0;s:5:"three";i:1;s:4:"five";i:2;s:17:"newline1
Newline2";i:3;s:7:"garçon";}
---
array (
  0 => 'three',
  1 => 'five',
  2 => 'newline1
Newline2',
  3 => 'garçon',
)
```

---

**One leg down the rabbit hole...** The above works fine even if double quotes occur in a string value, but if a string value contains `";` or some other monkeywrenching sbustring, you'll need to go a little further and implement "lookarounds".  My new pattern

checks that the leading `s` is:

- the start of the entire input string or
- preceded by `;`

and checks that the `";` is:

- at the end of the entire input string or
- followed by `}` or
- followed by a string or integer declaration `s:` or `i:`

I haven't test each and every possibility; in fact, I am relatively unfamiliar with all of the possibilities in a serialized string because I never elect to work with serialized data -- always json in modern applications. If there are additional possible leading or trailing characters, leave a comment and I'll extend the lookarounds.

Extended snippet:  ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/SApBV))

```
$corrupted_byte_counts = <<<STRING
a:12:{i:0;s:3:"three";i:1;s:5:"five";i:2;s:2:"newline1
newline2";i:3;s:6:"garçon";i:4;s:111:"double " quote \"escaped";i:5;s:1:"a,comma";i:6;s:9:"a:colon";i:7;s:0:"single 'quote";i:8;s:999:"semi;colon";s:5:"assoc";s:3:"yes";i:9;s:1:"monkey";wrenching doublequote-semicolon";s:3:"s:";s:9:"val s: val";}
STRING;

$repaired = preg_replace_callback(
        '/(?<=^|;)s:\d+:"(.*?)";(?=$|}|[si]:)/s',
        //^^^^^^^^--------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^-- some additional validation
        function ($m) {
            return 's:' . strlen($m[1]) . ":\"{$m[1]}\";";
        },
        $corrupted_byte_counts
    );

echo "corrupted serialized array:\n$corrupted_byte_counts";
echo "\n---\n";
echo "repaired serialized array:\n$repaired";
echo "\n---\n";
print_r(unserialize($repaired));
```

Output:

```
corrupted serialized array:
a:12:{i:0;s:3:"three";i:1;s:5:"five";i:2;s:2:"newline1
newline2";i:3;s:6:"garçon";i:4;s:111:"double " quote \"escaped";i:5;s:1:"a,comma";i:6;s:9:"a:colon";i:7;s:0:"single 'quote";i:8;s:999:"semi;colon";s:5:"assoc";s:3:"yes";i:9;s:1:"monkey";wrenching doublequote-semicolon";s:3:"s:";s:9:"val s: val";}
---
repaired serialized array:
a:12:{i:0;s:5:"three";i:1;s:4:"five";i:2;s:17:"newline1
newline2";i:3;s:7:"garçon";i:4;s:24:"double " quote \"escaped";i:5;s:7:"a,comma";i:6;s:7:"a:colon";i:7;s:13:"single 'quote";i:8;s:10:"semi;colon";s:5:"assoc";s:3:"yes";i:9;s:39:"monkey";wrenching doublequote-semicolon";s:2:"s:";s:10:"val s: val";}
---
Array
(
    [0] => three
    [1] => five
    [2] => newline1
newline2
    [3] => garçon
    [4] => double " quote \"escaped
    [5] => a,comma
    [6] => a:colon
    [7] => single 'quote
    [8] => semi;colon
    [assoc] => yes
    [9] => monkey";wrenching doublequote-semicolon
    [s:] => val s: val
)
```

Answer (score 3):

[Here is an Online Tool](https://puvox.software/tools/serialization-fixer.php) for fixing a corrupted serialized string.

I'd like to add that this mostly happens due to a search and replace done on the DB and the serialization data(*specially* the `key length`) doesn't get updated as per the replace and that causes the "corruption".

Nonetheless, The above tool uses the following logic to fix the serialization data ([Copied From Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38890855/807104)).

```
function error_correction_serialise($string){
    // at first, check if "fixing" is really needed at all. After that, security checkup.
    if ( unserialize($string) !== true &&  preg_match('/^[aOs]:/', $string) ) {
         $string = preg_replace_callback( '/s\:(\d+)\:\"(.*?)\";/s',    function($matches){return 's:'.strlen($matches[2]).':"'.$matches[2].'";'; },   $string );
    }
    return $string;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to alter the collation type to `utf8_unicode_ci` and the problem will be fixed.

Comment: What specific character in the OP's sample data do you believe will be modified by changing the collation to `utf8_unicode_ci`?  I have my doubts on this one.

Comment: This also actually worked for me (apart from r00tAcc3ss' answer) any word from someone clarifying why? As background, I take data from an API call to a ResourceSpace application, store it in an array, serialize it and save it. The serialized data was having issues being saved so i had to manually encode it to UTF-8, I was playing around with collation and character set in the DB, and finally was left with utf8_general_ci collation, when I changed it to utf8_unicode_ci, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was storing serialized data in `BLOB` field of MySQL DB which apparently wasn't big enough to contain the whole value and truncated it. Such a string obviously could not be unserialized.
Once converted that field to `MEDIUMBLOB` the problem dissipated.
Also it may be needed to switch in table options `ROW_FORMAT` to `DYNAMIC` or `COMPRESSED`.

Comment: Me to - although mine was a `TEXT` field and as such truncated at 65kb.

Comment: This question does not suffer from truncation.  The OP's question/issue is specifically dealing with the fact that (likely do to an inappropriate substring replacement on the "final array element" of the serialized string) there is an incorrect byte count in the serialized string.  Please only post answers that directly deal with the question asked.

Answer (score 1):

After having tried some things on this page without success I had a look in the page-source and remarked that all quotes in the serialized string have been replaced by html-entities.
Decoding these entities helps avoiding much headache:

```
$myVar = html_entity_decode($myVar);
```

Comment: This question does not suffer from html encoded entities in the serialized string.  The OP's question/issue is specifically dealing with the fact that (likely do to an inappropriate substring replacement on the "final array element" of the serialized string) there is an incorrect byte count in the serialized string.  Please only post answers that directly deal with the question asked.

Comment: @mickmackusa This question is almost 7 years old and my answer ~1,5. Nevertheless nice that you engage so much!

Comment: I love SO pages -- young and old.  I am looking out for researchers that don't know the difference between a good answer and a not-so-good answer.  This page, unfortunatey, is full of off-topic advice.

Comment: Great! There is already qualitiy control and voting, but I've no reason to stop you ;-)

Comment: Oh no, have a look. There are upvoted answers that should be downvoted.  Too many people can't differentiate.  On this page, the vote tally is absolutely no indication of quality / appropriateness.  I am not going to waste my time downvoting because my downvote won't make a dent on the tally.  The best I can do is leave comments to explain what is good/bad/ugly.

Comment: I found this issue by the headline, and the described step was a solution for my own problem according to the headline. And someone found it helpful. So what?

Comment: That is the next thing on my list to do.  (I'm working my way up the page from the bottom)  -- Fix the question to clarify the Title and Question Body.

Comment: So you think the question is still relevant to "Hotaru CMS"? Maybe the old code-base was completely replaced?

Comment: The `Hotaru CMS` part is irrelevant to researchers.  The relevant part is explaining that the corruption is limited to a bad byte count.

Comment: Ok, then good luck and see you at another question. I'm sure to see you again when you're so busy ;-)

Comment: This solution dose not work for the string '. Dose anyone solve this?

Comment: @LeoS it depends exclusively on your string which solution might work. So if you've a special string and can't find a sufficient answer on this page or on Stack Overflow in general then open a new question and post your string there.

Answer (score 1):

change the column size of the particular field(LONGTEXT)

Answer (score 1):

**You can use this for all case:**

```
$newdata = preg_replace_callback(
    '/(?<=^|\{|;)s:(\d+):\"(.*?)\";(?=[asbdiO]\:\d|N;|\}|$)/s',
    function($m){
        return 's:' . strlen($m[2]) . ':"' . $m[2] . '";';
    },
    $badData
);
```

Comment: Just needed a little work on the formatting!

Answer (score 0):

Another reason of this problem can be column type of "payload" sessions table. If you have huge data on session, a text column wouldn't be enough. You will need MEDIUMTEXT or even LONGTEXT.

Comment: This question does not suffer from truncation. The OP's question/issue is specifically dealing with the fact that (likely do to an inappropriate substring replacement on the "final array element" of the serialized string) there is an incorrect byte count in the serialized string. Please only post answers that directly deal with the question asked.

Answer (score -1):

So, we have two scenerios:

1 - already corrupted serialised data stored in SQL (my case) - that needs to be fixed

2 - make sure to not store any corrupted serialised data in the future

I have been there..

1 - couldn't manage with good solution for that.

- tried functions to recount characters posted above
- tried that online solution posted above

but the offset error still appears but in different offset.
Gave up and finished with sending data one more time and serialise again with 2.

2 - I have tried

```php
$string=base64_encode(serialize($obj));
unserialize(base64_decode($string));
```

and that did the job when sending data to MySQL one more time.

In my case corrupted data were submitted on webpage in foreign language - with special characters and some different encoding. Something didn't work well with preparing datas to serialise and to store.

Maybe it will help someone.

Comment: You should have configured your PHP/mysql properly. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Comment: yeah I know, I agree- and it rather is. Issue might be that that is quite old system to deal with - and effects of doing some changes may be quite unpredictable. But I need to see what I can do. Thing is that solution did the job and solved the problem for now.