# unserialize not working

Tags: php, json, serialization, deserialization

i am trying to unserialize string that is stored in mysql table.

following is the string stored in mysql table.

```
a:3:{s:15:\"purchase_amount\";d:500;s:4:\"more\";d:7;s:4:\"less\";d:11.5;}
```

at the time of insertion i had written following code.

```
addslashes(serialize(array('purchase_amount' => $values['purchase_amount'], 'more' => $values['transportaion_cost_gretter'], 'less' => $values['transportaion_cost_lesser'])))
```

At retrieval i had written followin code.

```
unserialize(stripslashes($row->getTransportaionCost()));
```

i am getting following error.

```
Notice: unserialize() [function.unserialize]: Error at offset 5 of 98 bytes
```

EDIT:

i tried json_encode and json_decode...

following is json data in mysql table

```
{"purchase_amount":500,"more":7,"less":11.5}
```

Following is the json decode in php.

```
var_dump(json_decode($row->getTransportaionCost())); //null
```

can any one tell me what is the problem ?

Comment: have you tried `unserialize(stripslashes($row->getTransportaionCost()));`?

Comment: you added slashes then you want unserialize before removing the slashes

Comment: yes i tried unserialize(stripslashes($row->getTransportaionCost())); but still not working.

Comment: @Hardik its not a json string, have you tried just to `var_dump($row->getTransportaionCost())` to see what the actual value is? as it may actually be double slashed, BTW you dont need to add slashes in the first place.

Comment: it returns `string '{&quot;purchase_amount&quot;:500,&quot;more&quot;:7,&quot;less&quot;:11.5}' (length=74)`

Comment: It looks like the quotes are getting encoded. Try running html_entity_decode before you unserialize it as well.

Comment: You should look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/10152996/1226894

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from when you store your data in the database, those antislashes shouldn't be here. Remove the addslashes, it will work better