# Saved state generates notice "error at offset"

Tags: php, serialization

I'm trying to `unserialize` a saved instance state of an object but my `serialized` object cannot be resumed due to an *"error at offset"* error.

This applies to all objects I try to unserialize, even the most simplest of objects.

```
class Object
{
    protected $variable = true;
}

$object = serialize(new Object());
$string = 'O:6:"Object":1:{s:11:"*variable";b:1;}';

echo $object."\n";
echo "length: ". strlen($object)."\n\n";
echo $string . "\n"; // Strangely 2 characters shorter than $object
echo "length: ". strlen($string)."\n";

unserialize($object); // Works
unserialize($string); // Does not work
```

This code outputs:

```
O:6:"Object":1:{s:11:"*variable";b:1;}
length: 40 

O:6:"Object":1:{s:11:"*variable";b:1;} 
length: 38 

Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 33 of 38 bytes
```

I'm stuck, why can I not unserialize saved strings?

Comment: @Baba Ok, missed that question. I'll try to encode to base64 before saving.

Comment: + for observation .... looking at your question .. this could be a common mistake .... you can also use `hex` to save

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two missing characters are null bytes that are used for the protected attribute. You cannot *see* them but they are still there. Thus, your `$string` is just not a valid serialization.

### Update:

Actually the null bytes can be made visible (with the invalid character symbol) in UTF-8 encoding. You can see it in [this demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d9f8ac478722ee2e33432b1a73dd7b7d30573dad) if you select **Output:** <kbd>Textbox</kbd>

```
string(40) "O:6:"Object":1:{s:11:"�*�variable";b:1;}"
```

Comment: Ok thank you, suggested solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10152904/unserialize-function-unserialize-error-at-offset) is to encode to base64 before saving.

Comment: Why would you encode it with base64? Just store it in a _binary_ column, not a _char_ column.

Comment: base64 is a viable solution if you have to transfer the string encoding neutral. However, you did not show how you save the values. base64 surely will work but maybe there is a better way.

Comment: @fab encoding to base64 worked like a charm! Wrikken: That is the plan. But that is not my question, my question is why the strings does not work.

Answer (score 1):

The `*` (`"\x2A"`) is actually terminated by 2 non-visible null bytes (`"\x0\x2A\x0"`). This means that you have to treat it as BINARY (which also means in database storing in BINARY/BLOB columns rather then CHAR/TEXT columns). Moral of the story is: PHP reserves to right to alter serialization methods *at any time*, so do not use anything BUT php to serialize strings, and treat serialized strings as BINARY rather then character data.

Comment: If PHP were to _“alter serialization methods at any time”_ – then I would probably not be able to unserialize something that I serialized a year ago now … even if I stuck to just using PHP and nothing else to do it.

Comment: That doesn't make sense, the result of serialization is not an implementation detail but part of the interface. It will *not* change without good cause. So, `$string` is not the result of a changed serialization method, it was just not stored correctly.

Comment: That _is_ unlikely yes, BUT it can make `unserialize()` detect the format & unserialize() as necessary, but make `serialize()` (==new data) only use a new format. I grant you that the chances of them _ever_ changing it are slim. But the meat of my answer was more: treat as binary, but I could have worded that better.

Comment: "But the meat of my answer was more: treat as binary" - with that I happily agree

Comment: As I said, the changes are very slim, and most likely backwards compatible (there already have been changes, for instance [check this example in PHP4](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2675d9ecc581d7d6d547df74ebf6def8c53313cd) and see what a 'weird' property it creates, as PHP4 had no notion of protected/private).