# unserialize Error at offset 5 of 9 bytes

Tags: php, arrays, serialization, deserialization

I'm trying to pass an array trough a html-form input field.
Using serialize to pass it and then unserialize to read the array again. I have multiple input fields.

```
$test = array('name' => 'Sander', 'type' => 'melon');

echo '<input type="hidden" name="rank[]" value="'.serialize($test).'" >';
```

Then If I want to unserialize it and show the data it gives an error:

```
$list = $_POST['rank'];
var_dump($list);
var_dump(unserialize($list[0]));
```

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [unserialize() \[function.unserialize\]: Error at offset](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10152904/unserialize-function-unserialize-error-at-offset)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using serialize I'm just using urlencode() and urldecode().

Changed the array to a different format.

```
$info = 'name=Sander&type=melon';

echo '<input type="hidden" name="rank[]" value="'.urlencode($info).'" >';
```

Then I can simply display the values like this:

```
if(!empty($_POST['rank'])){

    $list = $_POST['rank'];
    $listSize = count($list);

    for($i=0;$i<$listSize;$i++){

        parse_str(urldecode($list[$i]), $output);
        var_dump($output);  
    }

}
```

**Problem is solved :)**

Answer (score 6):

You most likely need to pass the serialized string through [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) before outputting.

To process it then, use [`urldecode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) before `unserialize()`.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
 $list = urldecode($_GET['rank']);
//var_dump($list);
var_dump(unserialize($list));
$test = array('name' => 'Sander', 'type' => 'melon');?>
<form >
<input type='hidden' name='rank' value='<?php echo serialize($test);?>' >
<input type="submit" >
</form>
```

Comment: Instead of array, I made a string in the following form: "name=Sander&type=melon". This worked!

Answer (score 0):

This is because when you add serialized data in html input, it produces malformed html tag

```
<input type="hidden" name="rank[]" value="a:2:{s:4:"name";s:6:"Sander";s:4:"type";s:5:"melon";}" >
```

see the " placements. Due to this your post data is incomplete

```
var_dump($_POST['rank']);
```

produces

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(9) "a:2:{s:4:"
}
```

why dont you try json_encode and json_decode ?

Comment: [JSON syntax](http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_syntax.asp) uses double quotes as well for strings, you'd have to `urlencode()` to prevent the behavior in this case as well.