# What does findSerializeError function do?

Tags: php

I periodically stumble upon the `unserialize(): Error at offset` error when unserializing data from database. I'm using base64_encode\base64_decode to smooth operations and it worked before but if fails now. I've found the [findSerializeError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10152904/unserialize-function-unserialize-error-at-offset/10152996#10152996) function here but can't figure out what it does. If I knew what it does, I would be able to fix serializing errors in future myself. I'd appreciate if anyone explained me what this function does. Here is the code of the function:

```
function findSerializeError($data1) {
    echo "<pre>";
    $data2 = preg_replace ( '!s:(\d+):"(.*?)";!e', "'s:'.strlen('$2').':\"$2\";'",$data1 );
    $max = (strlen ( $data1 ) > strlen ( $data2 )) ? strlen ( $data1 ) : strlen ( $data2 );

    echo $data1 . PHP_EOL;
    echo $data2 . PHP_EOL;

    for($i = 0; $i < $max; $i ++) {

        if (@$data1 {$i} !== @$data2 {$i}) {

            echo "Diffrence ", @$data1 {$i}, " != ", @$data2 {$i}, PHP_EOL;
            echo "\t-> ORD number ", ord ( @$data1 {$i} ), " != ", ord ( @$data2 {$i} ), PHP_EOL;
            echo "\t-> Line Number = $i" . PHP_EOL;

            $start = ($i - 20);
            $start = ($start < 0) ? 0 : $start;
            $length = 40;

            $point = $max - $i;
            if ($point < 20) {
                $rlength = 1;
                $rpoint = - $point;
            } else {
                $rpoint = $length - 20;
                $rlength = 1;
            }

            echo "\t-> Section Data1  = ", substr_replace ( substr ( $data1, $start, $length ), "<b style=\"color:green\">{$data1 {$i}}</b>", $rpoint, $rlength ), PHP_EOL;
            echo "\t-> Section Data2  = ", substr_replace ( substr ( $data2, $start, $length ), "<b style=\"color:red\">{$data2 {$i}}</b>", $rpoint, $rlength ), PHP_EOL;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Just add return `$data2` to return the fixed version

Comment: @Baba, thanks! But I'm curios what the fixed version is :)

Comment: All i did was re-calculate the length with `preg_replace`

Comment: @Baba, what was you trying to replace with preg_replace?