# PDO escape serialised string

Tags: php, database, serialization, pdo, escaping

Is it possible to escape a serialized string using PDO before it is inserted in the database?

I've built something where content from a WYSIWYG editor will be serialized. If someone pastes text from Word to the editor, and saves, I'll get the following error because multiple style tags where added:

```
unserialize(): Error at offset 105 of 1020
```

I've tried saying don't paste from Word haha, however I would like to build it so that it is possible even it's not the best way to do it.

I found the PDO function quote, but I'm not sure if that is what I'm looking for.
Besides that function, I couldn't find any other solutions. I'm already using PDO prepared statements.

I would like to know if it is possible. Thanks for the effort.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is related to encoding.

You should do base64_encode before save and base64_decode after it. As wrote [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10152996/1923681):

```
$toDatabse = base64_encode(serialize($data));  // Save to database
$fromDatabase = unserialize(base64_decode($data)); //Getting Save Format
```

Also, to avoid problems with encoding when you connect to database execute this SQL request:

```
"SET NAMES 'utf8'"
```