# unserialize in php not return any value

Tags: php, kohana

I am unserializing below string  but its not returning anything.

> a:57:{s:10:"THEME_NAME";s:5:"green";s:16:"PUBLIC_ADS_LIMIT";s:1:"5";s:17:"PUBLIC_EDIT_LIMIT";s:1:"5";s:8:"SITENAME";s:10:"Abcdubai";s:5:";}

Comment: There seems a line break after `a:57:`. Is that the case in the original code as well? Also, if you're just echoing the result you might be missing the fact that on failure `unserialize()` returns `false`. Check what exactly the function returns by using `var_dump()` for example.

Comment: `Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 132 of 144 bytes` don't forget display all errors and you will see a notice

Comment: possible duplicate of [unserialize() \[function.unserialize\]: Error at offset](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10152904/unserialize-function-unserialize-error-at-offset)

Comment: No line break, actually. My mistake. But as @CodingInsane says, there's definitely an error. You probably have errors turned off.

Comment: Thanks boaz, There is no line break as you said, But var_dump() returns null . What is the solution for this issue?

Comment: You can check for the actual error here: https://www.functions-online.com/unserialize.html See @Neo duplicate suggestion.

Comment: @CodingInsane can you explain what exactly this error means

Comment: @Boaz  I am new to PHP . So can you make that string a working serialized object ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data you're unserializing is wrong

```
a:57{s:10:"THEME_NAME";s:5:"green";s:16:"PUBLIC_ADS_LIMIT";s:1:"5";s:17:"PUBLIC_EDIT_LIMIT";s:1:"5";s:8:"SITENAME";s:10:"Abcdubai";s:5:";}
```

if you try to unserialize it with error reporting E_ALL you will see a notice

```
$data = 'a:57{s:10:"THEME_NAME";s:5:"green";s:16:"PUBLIC_ADS_LIMIT";s:1:"5";s:17:"PUBLIC_EDIT_LIMIT";s:1:"5";s:8:"SITENAME";s:10:"Abcdubai";s:5:";}';

var_dump($data);
```

you will get

```
Notice: unserialize(): Error
```

because

- `a:57` is the array length and from the data you have it's clearly not `57`.
- `s:` points to the length of string `s:10:"Abcdubai"` the string `Abcdubai` is not 10 in length it's 8 so you need to change that to `s:8:"Abcdubai"`
- Finally you have `s:5:";` at the end for the same reason `s:5` means a string with 5 characters in length and it's empty with a one double quote

  ```
  <?php
  // this the valid data
   $data = 'a:4:{s:10:"THEME_NAME";s:5:"green";s:16:"PUBLIC_ADS_LIMIT";s:1:"5";s:17:"PUBLIC_EDIT_LIMIT";s:1:"5";s:8:"SITENAME";s:8:"Abcdubai";}';

  $data = unserialize($data);

  // accessing the valid serialized data
  echo $data['THEME_NAME'];
  echo $data['PUBLIC_ADS_LIMIT'];
  echo $data['PUBLIC_EDIT_LIMIT'];
  echo $data['SITENAME'];
  ```

you can try this method to solve formatting issues

```
   function fixUnserializeFormatting($data){
       // fix string length (will fix s:)
       $data = preg_replace('!s:(\d+):"(.*?)";!e', "'s:'.strlen('$2').':\"$2\";'", $data);
       // remove empty matches with one double qoute
       $data = preg_replace('/s\:+[0-9]+\:";/i', '', $data);

       // trying to get the right array length
       $strings = substr_count($data,';') / 2;        
       // fixing array length
       $data = preg_replace('/^a:+[0-9]+:/i', "a:{$strings}:", $data);

       // finally returning the formatted data
       return $data;    
   }
```

Usage

```
   $data = 'a:57:{s:10:"THEME_NAME";s:5:"green";s:16:"PUBLIC_ADS_LIMIT";s:1:"5";s:17:"PUBLIC_EDIT_LIMIT";s:1:"5";s:8:"SITENAME";s:10:"Abcdubai";s:5:";}';

   $data = fixUnserializeFormatting($data);

   var_dump(unserialize($data));
```