# What type of array is this in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, wordpress

As I'm not an advanced PHP programmer, my rudimentary knowledge on PHP says, PHP arrays are like below:

```
$indexed_array = array( 1, 'Toothless', 23, 2456 );
$associative_array = array( 1 => 'Toothless', 2 => 2456 );
$multidimensional_array = array( 'me' => 'Toothless', 'nature' => 'Fearless' );
```

And right now I came to know about the PHP shorthand `array()` property:

```
$shorthand_array = [ 1, 'Toothless', 23, 2456 ];
$shorthand_mixture = [ 'me' => 'Toothless', 1, 'nature' => 'Fearless' ]; *
```

<sub>* [source^](https://coderwall.com/p/uftu7g/php-5-4-shorthand-for-arrays)</sub>

I'm actually a fan of WordPress and in WordPress `postmeta` table, WP stores some `meta_value`s (type:*longtext*) in a text like this (no space, a pure block of string):

```
a:3:{i:571;s:16:"path/to/image.ext";i:572;s:16:"path/to/image.ext";i:411;s:16:"path/to/image.ext";}
```

using jsfiddle's TidyUp I understood that, it's an array:

```
a: 3: {
    i: 571;
    s: 16: "path/to/image.ext";
    i: 572;
    s: 16: "path/to/image.ext";
    i: 411;
    s: 16: "path/to/image.ext";
}
```

I can decipher this now that, `a` stands for `array`, value 3 means it has 3 indexes; `i` denotes `index` and it stored the ID of the attachment, and `s` denotes `string` (char. count besides every `s`) and it stored the path of the attachment. ...Using CMB2 plugin I found the same storage structure.

Now I'm working on a Raw PHP project where database structure and storage planning is on my own. So I'm thinking of something like this in repeating fields. I want to store common repeating fields under a same `meta_key`, and will retrieve the individual field and its associative value using an array like this.

BTW, I can't understand how can I store data in this format from PHP, what types of array is this? And how actually I can generate a complex string (actually an array) like this from user input?

Comment: This is not array, its serialized version of array . you can universalize it and get the array version .

Comment: possible duplicate of [unserialize() \[function.unserialize\]: Error at offset](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10152904/unserialize-function-unserialize-error-at-offset)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the PHP functions `serialize()` and `unserialize()`:

**serialize()**

http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

**unserialize()**

http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php