# unserialize(): Error at offset 181 of 849 bytes

Tags: php, serialization

**This works** -

```
$serialized = 'a:23:{s:6:"fields";a:5:{s:21:"display_name_creditor";s:1:"1";s:24:"display_name_constituent";s:1:"1";s:14:"email_creditor";s:1:"1";s:14:"phone_creditor";s:1:"1";s:12:"total_amount";s:1:"1";}s:5:"id_op";s:2:"in";s:8:"id_value";a:0:{}s:21:"receive_date_relative";s:1:"0";s:17:"receive_date_from";s:0:"";s:15:"receive_date_to";s:0:"";s:25:"contribution_status_id_op";s:2:"in";s:28:"contribution_status_id_value";a:1:{i:0;s:1:"1";}s:16:"total_amount_min";s:0:"";s:16:"total_amount_max";s:0:"";s:15:"total_amount_op";s:3:"lte";s:18:"total_amount_value";s:0:"";s:6:"gid_op";s:2:"in";s:9:"gid_value";a:0:{}s:8:"tagid_op";s:2:"in";s:11:"tagid_value";a:0:{}s:11:"description";s:20:"Soft Credit details.";s:13:"email_subject";s:0:"";s:8:"email_to";s:0:"";s:8:"email_cc";s:0:"";s:10:"permission";s:21:"access CiviContribute";s:6:"groups";s:0:"";s:9:"domain_id";i:1;}';
```

$result = unserialize($serialized);

**This does not** -

```
$serialized = 'a:23:{s:6:"fields";a:5:{s:21:"display_name_creditor";s:1:"1";s:24:"display_name_constituent";s:1:"1";s:14:"email_creditor";s:1:"1";s:14:"phone_creditor";s:1:"1";s:12:"amount";s:1:"1";}s:5:"id_op";s:2:"in";s:8:"id_value";a:0:{}s:21:"receive_date_relative";s:1:"0";s:17:"receive_date_from";s:0:"";s:15:"receive_date_to";s:0:"";s:25:"contribution_status_id_op";s:2:"in";s:28:"contribution_status_id_value";a:1:{i:0;s:1:"1";}s:16:"total_amount_min";s:0:"";s:16:"total_amount_max";s:0:"";s:15:"total_amount_op";s:3:"lte";s:18:"total_amount_value";s:0:"";s:6:"gid_op";s:2:"in";s:9:"gid_value";a:0:{}s:8:"tagid_op";s:2:"in";s:11:"tagid_value";a:0:{}s:11:"description";s:20:"Soft Credit details.";s:13:"email_subject";s:0:"";s:8:"email_to";s:0:"";s:8:"email_cc";s:0:"";s:10:"permission";s:21:"access CiviContribute";s:6:"groups";s:0:"";s:9:"domain_id";i:1;}'
```

I have just changed the `total_amount` field to `amount` and I receive this error --

```
unserialize(): Error at offset 181 of 849 bytes
```

I've checked the solution provided at [unserialize() [function.unserialize]: Error at offset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10152904/unserialize-function-unserialize-error-at-offset) & http://davidwalsh.name/php-serialize-unserialize-issues, but nothing worked.

Also tried using `base64_encode/decode before serialize/unserialize`

Any hints ?

Comment: Unserialize the working string, rename the index in the array and serialize it. If you don't know what you are doing, don't change the serialized string yourself.

Comment: We have a set of serialized value defined in the db before installation of our software for some known reason, which has a change of field_name. Hence, it is required to pre-edit those values, which I try to do here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second one is invalid the reason being that field `s:12:"amount"` states that this value is a string of length 12. However `amount` only has 6 bytes. so you want to use `s:6:"amount"`

That being said its probably easier to `unserialize` then make a change then `serialize` the new value.

Comment: O O -- is it, lemme try that. Thanks for replying!

Comment: @JitendraPurohit Yeah must be it. Basically it means `type:length:content`, _s_ stands for string.