# How to convert json data to array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have json string live below, I try to convert array but I am not success can anyone please help me, thank you advance.

```
Example 1 : s:59:"[{"item_id":"UTILITY CON CERNIERA","qty":1,"points":"110"}]";

Example 1 : s:109:"[{"item_id":"UTILITY CON CERNIERA","qty":1,"points":"110"},{"item_id":"PESA VALIGIA","qty":1,"points":"120"}]";
```

Comment: What you tried so for? put that code here.

Comment: That's not JSON. That looks like a `serialize()`'d JSON string.

Comment: What's outputting this? There's JSON, but it's inside a `serialize()`'d string, prepended with something else...

Comment: Thank you it's working using  unserialize()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data is `serialized` as well as `json encoded`. So you have to use:-

`json_decode`along with `unserialize` like below:-

```
<?php

$data = 's:59:"[{"item_id":"UTILITY CON CERNIERA","qty":1,"points":"110"}]"';
print_r(json_decode(unserialize($data),true));
?>
```

And

```
<?php

$data = 's:109:"[{"item_id":"UTILITY CON CERNIERA","qty":1,"points":"110"},{"item_id":"PESA VALIGIA","qty":1,"points":"120"}]"';
print_r(json_decode(unserialize($data),true));
?>
```

https://eval.in/590757    And   https://eval.in/590758

For more reference:-

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php

Answer (score 3):

It seems, that you have a serialized json, so try this:

```
$array = json_decode(unserialize($string), true);
```

**But** it also seems that your data is corrupted, that's why `unserialize` does not work correctly in some `PHP` versions. If this is your case then in this question you can find a way to fix this: [unserialize() [function.unserialize]: Error at offset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10152904/unserialize-function-unserialize-error-at-offset).

Answer (score 2):

Use [unserialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) and [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

```
json_decode(unserialize($string),true); // pass second argument true
```

> When true, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays.

Comment: This one returns an array as requested.

Answer (score -1):

seems like these are serialized string not json encoded..

use `json_decode(unserialize($string));` to get array.

Comment: `unserialize` will get you a string here, not an array.

Comment: yes @Gino Pane is correct it has serialized as well as json encoded string but you need to unserialize first

Answer (score -1):

Read http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

```
$array=json_decode($JSON_STRING,true);
```

> Second parameter in function is for getting result as an **Array**, by default it returns Object.