# Error at offset x of y bytes in bootstrap.inc

Tags: php, serialization, drupal, drupal-7

I am working to solve this error but unable to find the reason as I am new for drupal `Error at offset 2 of 16 bytes in bootstrap.inc on line 936`
when I open /var/www/html/mysite/includes/bootstrap.inc I have found this

```
function function variable_initialize($conf = array()) {
  // NOTE: caching the variables improves performance by 20% when serving
  // cached pages.
  if ($cached = cache_get('variables', 'cache_bootstrap')) {
    $variables = $cached->data;
  }
  else {
    // Cache miss. Avoid a stampede.
    $name = 'variable_init';
    if (!lock_acquire($name, 1)) {
      // Another request is building the variable cache.
      // Wait, then re-run this function.
      lock_wait($name);
      return variable_initialize($conf);
    }
    else {
      // Proceed with variable rebuild.
      $variables = array_map('unserialize', db_query('SELECT name, value FROM {variable}')->fetchAllKeyed());
      cache_set('variables', $variables, 'cache_bootstrap');
      lock_release($name);
    }
  }

  foreach ($conf as $name => $value) {
    $variables[$name] = $value;
  }

  return $variables;
}
```

error is showing on this line  `$variables = array_map('unserialize', db_query('SELECT name, value FROM {variable}')->fetchAllKeyed());`
I am unable to to solve it, what is the reason ?

Comment: @ericLavault i am still working on it, once your solution work let you know

Answer (score 0):

This error means that `unserialize()` fails to convert a serialized value back into a PHP value because of an invalid length (or a length mismatch) in the stored representation of the data.

The reason is that some variable was badly serialized, see this detailed [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10152996/2529954) for more info.

To resolve the issue, first check `variable` table and ensure the `value` data type is a **blob** type. For database portability blob fields must be used to store serialized data since PHP adds null bytes if objects are serialized. Null bytes cannot be stored in Postgres text or varchar fields. The exact type depends on the underlying database :

- MySQL : `LONGBLOB`
- PostgreSQL : `BYTEA`
- SQLite : `BLOB`

Then you need to identify the variable(s) causing the issue, run this code and check the output :

```
$var = array();
$broken_var = array();
$false = serialize(FALSE);

$rows = db_query('SELECT name, CONVERT (value USING utf8) FROM variable')->fetchAllKeyed();
foreach ($rows as $name => $value) {
  $var[$name] = @unserialize($value);
  if ($var[$name] === FALSE && $value !== $false) {
    $broken_var[$name] = $value;
  }
}

print_r($broken_var);
```

Once the "broken" variable is identified, you might want to delete it or reset it using `variable_del()` or `variable_set()`.

To prevent the issue, one should avoid setting variables manually and always use `variable_set()`.