# unserialize data in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, serialization

I saved my cart data to the `orders` table with the `serialize` method, now in my orders 'view' page, I want to display them to the user to show their order history.

How can I revert the previously serialized data to usable objects/arrays within PHP?

The code snippet of where I save the data: `$order->cart = serialize($cartItems);`.

The method I try to return my orders index view:

```
/**
 * Action to receive all orders from the current
 * logged-in user. This action will return the
 * 'front.orders' view with the orders compacted inside.
 *
 * @return orders view
 */
public function orders() {
    // get the orders from the current logged in user
    $orders = Order::where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->get();

    // view the `front.orders` page passing in the `orders` variable
    return view('front.orders', compact('orders'));
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`map()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-map) method to [unserialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) cart property for the whole collection:

```
$orders = $orders->map(function($i) {
    $i->cart = unserialize($i->cart);
    return $i;
});
```

Alternatively, you could use an [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) to automatically unserialize property:

```
public function getCartAttribute($value)
{
    return unserialize($value);
}
```

Or just [unserialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) the data in Blade:

```
@foreach ($orders as $order)
    {{ unserialize($order->cart)->someData }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: if i use map, how do i use my query to only get logged user orders and not all users?

Comment: @mafortis the code you've shown will get only logged in user's orders. Just use map after you're getting orders.

Comment: I GET ERROR OF `unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 91 bytes`

Comment: @mafortis it's not related to the question, so you may start another answer if you'll not handle it by yourself. You can start by reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10152904/unserialize-function-unserialize-error-at-offset).

Comment: ok its working now and here is my blade code, `@foreach($orderss as $order)<li>{{$order->cart}}</li>@endforeach` this is screenshot,  https://ibb.co/mSU2nG    how do i get info properly?

Answer (score 3):

Sure you can use built-in `unserialize()` function from previous answers.

But

Avoid using `unserialize()` in your code because of exloit:

https://www.notsosecure.com/remote-code-execution-via-php-unserialize/
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php

I would use secure simple lib from Magento 1:
https://github.com/bragento/magento-core/tree/1.9/lib/Unserialize

```
$parser = new Unserialize_Parser();
$parser->unserialize($yourStringWithArray)
```

Answer (score 1):

[serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) is just a built-in, variable handling, PHP function. The counterpart of this is [unserialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php).

Comment: tha't what i know, what i want to know it how to return my data in view?  this is what i have currently https://ibb.co/mSU2nG

Comment: You have to save the unserialized data in a variable -> `$data=unserialize($serializedData)`. After that you can access the data by using the index like `$data["name"]` for instance. Additionally I saw that you always get the same data. Is this just a "problem" with your test data or is it another issue?