# PHP: error: Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 438 of 750 bytes in

Tags: php, serialization

I tried to unserialize an serialized string:

```
$sri = 'a:8:{s:3:"key";s:32:"73b43c7df3604c8d725f856b219cffda";s:5:"email";s:19:"Aligh.Pro@gmail.com";s:4:"date";s:0:"";s:9:"user_info";a:4:{s:2:"id";i:2;s:5:"email";s:19:"Aligh.Pro@gmail.com";s:10:"first_name";s:5:"mahdi";s:8:"discount";s:4:"none";}s:9:"downloads";a:1:{i:0;a:3:{s:2:"id";i:44;s:8:"quantity";i:1;s:7:"options";a:2:{s:8:"quantity";i:1;s:8:"price_id";s:1:"1";}}}s:12:"cart_details";a:1:{i:0;a:10:{s:4:"name";s:17:"?????? ??";s:2:"id";i:44;s:11:"item_number";a:3:{s:2:"id";i:44;s:8:"quantity";i:1;s:7:"options";a:2:{s:8:"quantity";i:1;s:8:"price_id";s:1:"1";}}s:10:"item_price";d:20000;s:8:"quantity";i:1;s:8:"discount";d:0;s:8:"subtotal";d:20000;s:3:"tax";d:0;s:4:"fees";a:0:{}s:5:"price";d:20000;}}s:4:"fees";a:0:{}s:8:"currency";s:4:"RIAL";}';
$data_array = unserialize((string) $sri);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($data_array);
echo '</pre>';
```

but I saw this error:
Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 438 of 750 bytes in ...

I tried above serialized string by online unserialization. The string worked well.
but in my cumputer, it doesn't.

what's the problem?

Comment: `}}}s` there should be `,` definitelty.

Comment: the string `s:17:"?????? ??"` is not 17 Bytes long. After changing it to `s:9:"?????? ??"` unserialize worked (for me). I think, it's something with copy/paste and wrong encodings

Comment: Possible duplicate of [unserialize() \[function.unserialize\]: Error at offset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10152904/unserialize-function-unserialize-error-at-offset)

Comment: @u_mulder I did that it steal does'n work.

Comment: Because there are several occurences if this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Baba already wrote a great answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10152904/unserialize-function-unserialize-error-at-offset). If you are in need of a quick fix, this code will do the job.

```
$data = preg_replace_callback(
    '!s:(\d+):"(.*?)";!', 
    function($m) { 
        return 's:'.strlen($m[2]).':"'.$m[2].'";'; 
    }, 
    $sri);

var_dump(unserialize($data));
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, but still, i;m unable to understand that if the data is store via using serialize function, why wont it deserialize? why should we need this function?

Comment: You need to understand that a serialization is essentially a way to store an object as a string. In the representation you have a section that tells php the upcoming part will be a certain amount of characters long. This amount was somehow wrong in your serialized string. This code simply recalculates the lengths of all the sections. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Little addition to answer: regexp doesn't work on string containing line break characters. Something like

```
$sri = str_replace(["\n", "\r"], '', $sri);
```

should work fine.