# Extract value from multi dimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I need to extract the string "Post Title" from this array. I have no idea how to reach it.

```
a:1:
    {   i:0;
        a:5:  
        { 
        s:4:"data";s:9:"Post Title";    
        s:7:"attribs";a:0:{}
        s:8:"xml_base";s:0:"";
        s:17:"xml_base_explicit";b:0;
        s:8:"xml_lang";s:0:"";
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is no `array`.

Comment: It looks like the result of a serialize()

Comment: Should I unserialize? How should I grab the Value

Answer (score 1):

As the comments say, you have a serialized array. But there are two potential problems with using unserialize.

You should not use unserialize on untrusted data. There's a big warning in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php). If you don't trust the data fully, I suggest a safer alternative like `_safe_unserialize` used by myBB. You can find it on [github](https://github.com/mybb/mybb/blob/88858fca2ed0cd8afb9f24dc489e8d2de85cb5cf/inc/functions.php#L2012).

Second your string looks corrupted in one place. It should be `s:10:"Post Title";`. That means that unserialize/safe_unserialize will throw errors. To fix that, take a look at the first two answers of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10152904/unserialize-function-unserialize-error-at-offset/10152996).

After you did all that, and stored the unserialized data in - let's say $arr - you can access the post title via: `$array[0]['data']`.