# PHP Unserilize is not working

Tags: php, serialization

I am saving an serialized array in mysql database .
 and when i fetching result data from mysql and  printing that details it is printing .

```
 $data=$row['data'];



print_r( $data)
```

result is

```
a:8:{i:0;a:7:{s:2:"id";s:2:"16";s:4:"slug";s:8:"fieldset";s:4:"name";s:8:"Fieldset";s:4:"type";s:8:"fieldset";s:7:"options";s:0:"";s:9:"parent_id";s:1:"0";s:5:"value";s:0:"";}i:1;a:7:{s:2:"id";s:2:"20";s:4:"slug";s:9:"your-name";s:4:"name";s:9:"Your Name";s:4:"type";s:4:"text";s:7:"options";s:0:"";s:9:"parent_id";s:1:"0";s:5:"value";s:11:"SamueljalIL";}i:2;a:7:{s:2:"id";s:2:"21";s:4:"slug";s:10:"your-email";s:4:"name";s:10:"Your Email";s:4:"type";s:5:"email";s:7:"options";s:0:"";s:9:"parent_id";s:1:"0";s:5:"value";s:16:"dimitryg@msn.com";}i:3;a:7:{s:2:"id";s:2:"24";s:4:"slug";s:5:"phone";s:4:"name";s:5:"Phone";s:4:"type";s:4:"text";s:7:"options";s:0:"";s:9:"parent_id";s:1:"0";s:5:"value";s:11:"88621295115";}i:4;a:7:{s:2:"id";s:2:"22";s:4:"slug";s:12:"your-message";s:4:"name";s:12:"Your Message";s:4:"type";s:8:"textarea";s:7:"options";s:0:"";s:9:"parent_id";s:1:"0";s:5:"value";s:1876:"Havе yоu listenеd
 http://boletines.consumer.es/?p=50&amp;u=https://gdfgl/96D4u9";}i:5;a:7:{s:2:"id";s:2:"17";s:4:"slug";s:12:"verification";s:4:"name";s:12:"Verification";s:4:"type";s:12:"verification";s:7:"options";s:0:"";s:9:"parent_id";s:1:"0";s:5:"value";s:0:"";}i:6;a:7:{s:2:"id";s:2:"18";s:4:"slug";s:27:"please-enter-any-two-digits";s:4:"name";s:27:"Please enter any two digits";s:4:"type";s:6:"secret";s:7:"options";s:0:"";s:9:"parent_id";s:2:"17";s:5:"value";s:2:"82";}i:7;a:7:{s:2:"id";s:2:"19";s:4:"slug";s:6:"submit";s:4:"name";s:6:"Submit";s:4:"type";s:6:"submit";s:7:"options";s:0:"";s:9:"parent_id";s:2:"17";s:5:"value";s:0:"";}}
```

But when i try to unserilize this data it is not working

```
 $arr=unserialize($data);

  print_r($arr);
```

there is nothing printing here ;

Comment: Are you sure nothing gets printed?

Comment: '*In case the passed string is not unserializeable, FALSE is returned and E_NOTICE is issued.*' - Is your error reporting enabled?

Comment: is this your whole content of $data?
its seems the data is invalid... the string with the domain in it is not 1876 chars long, but 's:1876:"Havе yоu listenеd http [...]' says it has to be - 


any reason why you use serialize instead of json?

Comment: share whole of the code

Comment: `<b>Notice</b>:  unserialize(): Error at offset 891 of 1547 bytes`

Comment: Now you have given an error, see the duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10152904/unserialize-function-unserialize-error-at-offset

Comment: Error at offset 891 of 1547 bytes  . i got this kind of error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your serialized string has been damaged.  As I rub my crystal ball, I can imagine someone manually performed string replacements (inappropriately) to update the url that immediately follows `Have you listened` in the array at index `4`.

This is revealed after analyzing the data at this location:

```
s:1876:"Havе yоu listenеd
http://boletines.consumer.es/?p=50&amp;u=https://gdfgl/96D4u9";
```

You see this stored value has 81 bytes/characters in it.

The serialized data strictly claims that the value must have 1876 bytes/characters in it.

Ultimately, your serialized data has been compromised -- either the length or the value.

If you are not bothered by the current value, you can manually repair the serialized data with this:  https://3v4l.org/GqsHu

This is from a post of mine here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55074706/2943403

With the provided snippet, you can either repair the corrupted serialized data on the fly each time, or you can take the time to repair all corrupted data and update your database so that this headache doesn't present itself again.

Let this occurrence be a lesson to developers -- Never try to take a short cut to update serialized data.  You must unserialize it, modifying it, then re-serialize it so that a valid string is generated.

Comment: could you please help me to fetch the online gold price  from google or any other api ? If you can i will make it as other question

Comment: I am not at my computer anymore, I am spending time with my family.  When you post your question, be sure to include your research and best coding attempt.

Answer (score 0):

I think your serilized data truncate when storing into database. it might happen due to column length size. So increase you column length and try.

Comment: bu ti have enough column length . And there error is not due to column length .

Comment: What is the column type you have... VER/CHAR/TEXT? It's really important to know. I had the same issue. I had 'TEXT' as column type and after that, I change that to MEDIUMTEXT.