# Unserialize - Error at offset 9179 of 11507 bytes

Tags: php, serialization

I am using `php 7.1` and I want to `unserialize` the following value:

```
a:1:{s:13:"us-B07F11V8SM";a:32:{s:5:"price";s:7:"5250.00";s:8:"priceOld";s:0:"";s:15:"percentageSaved";i:0;s:8:"currency";s:1:"$";s:12:"currencyCode";s:3:"USD";s:12:"manufacturer";s:11:"Innosilicon";s:8:"category";s:0:"";s:12:"categoryPath";a:0:{}s:8:"merchant";s:10:"Amazon.com";s:4:"logo";s:0:"";s:6:"domain";s:10:"amazon.com";s:6:"rating";s:0:"";s:12:"reviewsCount";s:0:"";s:12:"availability";s:0:"";s:8:"orig_url";s:0:"";s:3:"ean";s:13:"0603432616995";s:3:"upc";s:0:"";s:3:"sku";s:0:"";s:4:"isbn";s:0:"";s:8:"woo_sync";s:0:"";s:8:"woo_attr";s:0:"";s:8:"features";a:16:{i:0;a:2:{s:4:"name";s:7:"Binding";s:5:"value";s:11:"Electronics";}i:1;a:2:{s:4:"name";s:5:"Brand";s:5:"value";s:11:"Innosilicon";}i:2;a:2:{s:4:"name";s:3:"EAN";s:5:"value";s:13:"0603432616995";}i:3;a:2:{s:4:"name";s:8:"EAN List";s:5:"value";s:31:"EAN List Element: 0603432616995";}i:4;a:2:{s:4:"name";s:15:"Item Dimensions";s:5:"value";s:12:"Weight: 1764";}i:5;a:2:{s:4:"name";s:5:"Label";s:5:"value";s:11:"Innosilicon";}i:6;a:2:{s:4:"name";s:12:"Manufacturer";s:5:"value";s:11:"Innosilicon";}i:7;a:2:{s:4:"name";s:18:"Package Dimensions";s:5:"value";s:12:"Weight: 1764";}i:8;a:2:{s:4:"name";s:16:"Package Quantity";s:5:"value";s:1:"1";}i:9;a:2:{s:4:"name";s:13:"Product Group";s:5:"value";s:12:"PC Accessory";}i:10;a:2:{s:4:"name";s:17:"Product Type Name";s:5:"value";s:25:"COMPUTER_DRIVE_OR_STORAGE";}i:11;a:2:{s:4:"name";s:9:"Publisher";s:5:"value";s:11:"Innosilicon";}i:12;a:2:{s:4:"name";s:6:"Studio";s:5:"value";s:11:"Innosilicon";}i:13;a:2:{s:4:"name";s:5:"Title";s:5:"value";s:198:"50Ksol/s 620W, Innosilicon announces World Best Equihash Miner A9 ZMaster with PSU with low consumption Produce $80 to $100 a Day(In Stock) ready for shipment higher than D9 DecredMaster Asic Miner.";}i:14;a:2:{s:4:"name";s:3:"UPC";s:5:"value";s:12:"603432616995";}i:15;a:2:{s:4:"name";s:8:"UPC List";s:5:"value";s:30:"UPC List Element: 603432616995";}}s:9:"unique_id";s:13:"us-B07F11V8SM";s:5:"title";s:198:"50Ksol/s 620W, Innosilicon announces World Best Equihash Miner A9 ZMaster with PSU with low consumption Produce $80 to $100 a Day(In Stock) ready for shipment higher than D9 DecredMaster Asic Miner.";s:11:"description";s:0:"";s:3:"img";s:124:"http://coindation.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/50ksols-620w-innosilicon-announces-world-best-equihash-miner-a9-zmaster.jpg";s:3:"url";s:209:"https://www.amazon.com/Innosilicon-announces-Equihash-consumption-DecredMaster/dp/B07F11V8SM?SubscriptionId=AKIAIZ3S74HU3GOABUYQ&tag=coindation-20&linkCode=xm2&camp=2025&creative=165953&creativeASIN=B07F11V8SM";s:11:"last_update";s:10:"1534678571";s:5:"added";s:1:"1";s:7:"keyword";s:11:"Innosilicon";s:8:"img_file";s:83:"2018/07/50ksols-620w-innosilicon-announces-world-best-equihash-miner-a9-zmaster.jpg";s:5:"extra";a:29:{s:6:"locale";s:2:"us";s:13:"associate_tag";s:13:"coindation-20";s:9:"itemLinks";a:7:{i:0;a:2:{s:11:"Description";s:17:"Technical Details";s:3:"URL";s:219:"https://www.amazon.com/Innosilicon-announces-Equihash-consumption-DecredMaster/dp/tech-data/B07F11V8SM?SubscriptionId=AKIAIZ3S74HU3GOABUYQ&tag=coindation-20&linkCode=xm2&camp=2025&creative=386001&creativeASIN=B07F11V8SM";}i:1;a:2:{s:11:"Description";s:20:"Add To Baby Registry";s:3:"URL";s:188:"https://www.amazon.com/gp/registry/baby/add-item.html?asin.0=B07F11V8SM&SubscriptionId=AKIAIZ3S74HU3GOABUYQ&tag=coindation-20&linkCode=xm2&camp=2025&creative=386001&creativeASIN=B07F11V8SM";}i:2;a:2:{s:11:"Description";s:23:"Add To Wedding Registry";s:3:"URL";s:191:"https://www.amazon.com/gp/registry/wedding/add-item.html?asin.0=B07F11V8SM&SubscriptionId=AKIAIZ3S74HU3GOABUYQ&tag=coindation-20&linkCode=xm2&camp=2025&creative=386001&creativeASIN=B07F11V8SM";}i:3;a:2:{s:11:"Description";s:15:"Add To Wishlist";s:3:"URL";s:192:"https://www.amazon.com/gp/registry/wishlist/add-item.html?asin.0=B07F11V8SM&SubscriptionId=AKIAIZ3S74HU3GOABUYQ&tag=coindation-20&linkCode=xm2&camp=2025&creative=386001&creativeASIN=B07F11V8SM";}i:4;a:2:{s:11:"Description";s:13:"Tell A Friend";s:3:"URL";s:161:"https://www.amazon.com/gp/pdp/taf/B07F11V8SM?SubscriptionId=AKIAIZ3S74HU3GOABUYQ&tag=coindation-20&linkCode=xm2&camp=2025&creative=386001&creativeASIN=B07F11V8SM";}i:5;a:2:{s:11:"Description";s:20:"All Customer Reviews";s:3:"URL";s:165:"https://www.amazon.com/review/product/B07F11V8SM?SubscriptionId=AKIAIZ3S74HU3GOABUYQ&tag=coindation-20&linkCode=xm2&camp=2025&creative=386001&creativeASIN=B07F11V8SM";}i:6;a:2:{s:11:"Description";s:10:"All Offers";s:3:"URL";s:167:"https://www.amazon.com/gp/offer-listing/B07F11V8SM?SubscriptionId=AKIAIZ3S74HU3GOABUYQ&tag=coindation-20&linkCode=xm2&camp=2025&creative=386001&creativeASIN=B07F11V8SM";}}s:8:"imageSet";a:5:{i:0;a:7:{s:10:"attributes";a:1:{s:8:"Category";s:7:"variant";}s:11:"SwatchImage";s:71:"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51xuTtKHb2L._SL30_.jpg";s:10:"SmallImage";s:71:"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51xuTtKHb2L._SL75_.jpg";s:14:"ThumbnailImage";s:71:"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51xuTtKHb2L._SL75_.jpg";s:9:"TinyImage";s:72:"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51xuTtKHb2L._SL110_.jpg";s:11:"MediumImage";s:72:"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51xuTtKHb2L._SL160_.jpg";s:10:"LargeImage";s:64:"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51xuTtKHb2L.jpg";}i:1;a:7:{s:10:"attributes";a:1:{s:8:"Category";s:7:"variant";}s:11:"SwatchImage";s:71:"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/517O2NFtK0L._SL30_.jpg";s:10:"SmallImage";s:71:"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/517O2NFtK0L._SL75_.jpg";s:14:"ThumbnailImage";s:71:"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/517O2NFtK0L._SL75_.jpg";s:9:"TinyImage";s:72:"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/517O2NFtK0L._SL110_.jpg";s:11:"MediumImage";s:72:"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/517O2NFtK0L._SL160_.jpg";s:10:"LargeImage";s:64:"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/517O2NFtK0L.jpg";}i:2;a:7:{s:10:"attributes";a:1:{s:8:"Category";s:7:"variant";}s:11:"SwatchImage";s:71:"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51-Ij429VEL._SL30_.jpg";s:10:"SmallImage";s:71:"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51-Ij429VEL._SL75_.jpg";s:14:"ThumbnailImage";s:71:"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51-Ij429VEL._SL75_.jpg";s:9:"TinyImage";s:72:"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51-Ij429VEL._SL110_.jpg";s:11:"MediumImage";s:72:"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51-Ij429VEL._SL160_.jpg";s:10:"LargeImage";s:64:"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51-Ij429VEL.jpg";}i:3;a:7:{s:10:"attributes";a:1:{s:8:"Category";s:7:"variant";}s:11:"SwatchImage";s:71:"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51PxlCNXMuL._SL30_.jpg";s:10:"SmallImage";s:71:"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51PxlCNXMuL._SL75_.jpg";s:14:"ThumbnailImage";s:71:"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51PxlCNXMuL._SL75_.jpg";s:9:"TinyImage";s:72:"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51PxlCNXMuL._SL110_.jpg";s:11:"MediumImage";s:72:"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51PxlCNXMuL._SL160_.jpg";s:10:"LargeImage";s:64:"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51PxlCNXMuL.jpg";}i:4;a:7:{s:10:"attributes";a:1:{s:8:"Category";s:7:"primary";}s:11:"SwatchImage";s:71:"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/517O2NFtK0L._SL30_.jpg";s:10:"SmallImage";s:71:"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/517O2NFtK0L._SL75_.jpg";s:14:"ThumbnailImage";s:71:"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/517O2NFtK0L._SL75_.jpg";s:9:"TinyImage";s:72:"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/517O2NFtK0L._SL110_.jpg";s:11:"MediumImage";s:72:"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/517O2NFtK0L._SL160_.jpg";s:10:"LargeImage";s:64:"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/517O2NFtK0L.jpg";}}s:11:"AmountSaved";s:0:"";s:15:"PercentageSaved";s:0:"";s:31:"IsEligibleForSuperSaverShipping";s:0:"";s:15:"customerReviews";a:0:{}s:16:"editorialReviews";a:0:{}s:10:"smallImage";s:71:"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/517O2NFtK0L._SL75_.jpg";s:11:"mediumImage";s:72:"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/517O2NFtK0L._SL160_.jpg";s:10:"largeImage";s:64:"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/517O2NFtK0L.jpg";s:12:"addToCartUrl";s:100:"http://www.amazon.com/gp/aws/cart/add.html?ASIN.1=B07F11V8SM&Quantity.1=1&AssociateTag=coindation-20";s:4:"ASIN";s:10:"B07F11V8SM";s:14:"itemAttributes";a:68:{s:5:"Actor";s:0:"";s:6:"Artist";s:0:"";s:11:"AspectRatio";s:0:"";s:14:"AudienceRating";s:0:"";s:11:"AudioFormat";s:0:"";s:7:"Binding";s:11:"Electronics";s:5:"Brand";s:11:"Innosilicon";s:13:"CEROAgeRating";s:0:"";s:12:"ClothingSize";s:0:"";s:5:"Color";s:0:"";s:7:"Creator";s:0:"";s:10:"Department";s:0:"";s:8:"Director";s:0:"";s:3:"EAN";s:13:"0603432616995";s:7:"EANList";s:0:"";s:7:"Edition";s:0:"";s:5:"EISBN";s:0:"";s:15:"EpisodeSequence";s:0:"";s:13:"ESRBAgeRating";s:0:"";s:7:"Feature";a:4:{i:0;s:137:"?A9 Hashrate is 50Ksol/s, can make about $80 to $100 a day according to 25th, June calculation. We can not guarantee the later profits.";i:1;s:222:"?Please check Innosilicon A9 on website about it's Profits before you buy and make serious consideration, Because we do not accept any return or refund of this miner. Ship By DHL, generally need 3-7 days, you can get it.";i:2;s:156:"?Power Consumption: 620W (+/-8%, normal mode, at the wall, with 12.4j/ksol efficiency , Include Innosilicon PSU power supply ATX�Power�(12V�9�*�6pin)";i:3;s:162:"?Almost the most profitable Virtual Currency Miner machine right now. Antminer S9 produce about $6 a day. A9 can do $80 to $100 a day according to 25th profits.";}s:6:"Format";s:0:"";s:5:"Genre";s:0:"";s:16:"HardwarePlatform";s:0:"";s:21:"HazardousMaterialType";s:0:"";s:14:"IsAdultProduct";s:0:"";s:13:"IsAutographed";s:0:"";s:4:"ISBN";s:0:"";s:20:"IsEligibleForTradeIn";s:0:"";s:13:"IsMemorabilia";s:0:"";s:13:"IssuesPerYear";s:0:"";s:14:"ItemDimensions";s:0:"";s:14:"ItemPartNumber";s:0:"";s:5:"Label";s:11:"Innosilicon";s:9:"Languages";s:0:"";s:15:"LegalDisclaimer";s:0:"";s:22:"ManufacturerMaximumAge";s:0:"";s:22:"ManufacturerMinimumAge";s:0:"";s:36:"ManufacturerPartsWarrantyDescription";s:0:"";s:9:"MediaType";s:0:"";s:5:"Model";s:0:"";s:3:"MPN";s:0:"";s:13:"NumberOfDiscs";s:0:"";s:14:"NumberOfIssues";s:0:"";s:13:"NumberOfItems";s:0:"";s:13:"NumberOfPages";s:0:"";s:14:"NumberOfTracks";s:0:"";s:15:"OperatingSystem";s:0:"";s:15:"PackageQuantity";s:1:"1";s:10:"PartNumber";s:0:"";s:8:"Platform";s:0:"";s:12:"ProductGroup";s:12:"PC Accessory";s:22:"ProductTypeSubcategory";s:0:"";s:15:"PublicationDate";s:0:"";s:9:"Publisher";s:11:"Innosilicon";s:10:"RegionCode";s:0:"";s:11:"ReleaseDate";s:0:"";s:11:"RunningTime";s:0:"";s:18:"SeikodoProductCode";s:0:"";s:4:"Size";s:0:"";s:3:"SKU";s:0:"";s:6:"Studio";s:11:"Innosilicon";s:18:"SubscriptionLength";s:0:"";s:12:"TradeInValue";s:0:"";s:3:"UPC";s:12:"603432616995";s:7:"UPCList";s:0:"";s:8:"Warranty";s:0:"";s:12:"WEEETaxValue";s:0:"";s:17:"PackageDimensions";s:0:"";}s:14:"toLowToDisplay";s:0:"";s:12:"availability";s:0:"";s:14:"lowestNewPrice";s:7:"5250.00";s:15:"lowestUsedPrice";s:0:"";s:22:"lowestCollectiblePrice";s:0:"";s:22:"lowestRefurbishedPrice";s:0:"";s:8:"totalNew";s:2:"10";s:9:"totalUsed";s:1:"0";s:16:"totalCollectible";s:1:"0";s:16:"totalRefurbished";s:1:"0";s:4:"date";s:0:"";s:6:"author";s:0:"";s:6:"source";s:0:"";s:6:"domain";s:0:"";}}}
```

However, I get the following error: `Error at offset 9179 of 11507 bytes`

The `unserialize` function returns `false`.

Any suggestions what is wrong with my string? I serialized the value beforehand, so I am not sure why there is an error in unserializing it.

I appreciate your replies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably an encoding issue. The issue starts with the string

```
s:137:"?A9 Hashrate is 50Ksol/s ...
```

When I copy the string it's only 135 bytes long, and it unserializes correctly with s:135:"...

You could correct those strings manually (there're only 4 of them in your example), or find out what charset you used for serialization and use the same for unserialization. I think the ? mark was a 3-byte character originally.

This issue came up in the past. For a semi automated solution you can try the regex in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10152904/unserialize-function-unserialize-error-at-offset/21389439#21389439). But that regex will choke when you have double quotes followed by semi-colons in your serialized strings.

Comment: Is there any automated way to fix these kind of issues?

Comment: See the last paragraph (I added it now).