# Why does codeigniter & Linux server throws unserialize() session data error when user tries to login

Tags: php, linux, codeigniter, session

I am developing an app using CodeIgniter and I have deployed this app on a linux server, the issues I am facing is this error
`ERROR - 2022-01-06 11:48:16 --> Severity: Notice  --> unserialize(): Error at offset 122 of 167 bytes /var/www/htmlaplib_core/libraries/Session.php 740` which prevent any user from logging in however on my local development environment I do not get this error, I have tried to find solutions on the internet but still I am not able to get collect solution.

This is the code that causes the issues during deployment.

```
function _unserialize($data)
{
    
    $data = @unserialize(strip_slashes($data));
    if (is_array($data))
    {
        foreach ($data as $key => $val)
        {
            if (is_string($val))
            {
                $data[$key] = str_replace('{{slash}}', '\\', $val);
            }
        }

        return $data;
    }

    return (is_string($data)) ? str_replace('{{slash}}', '\\', $data) : $data;
}
```

I will appreciate any help that I can get

Especially this line `$data = @unserialize(strip_slashes($data));`

This is the output of variable `$data` before `@unserialize()`

- `a:15:{s:10:"session_id";s:32:"aef2d2d8a8282132c6ebae6ccc4b94a8";s:10:"ip_address";s:3:"::1";s:10:"user_agent";s:114:"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.71 Safari/537.36";s:13:"last_activity";i:1641453560;s:9:"user_data";s:0:"";s:4:"LANG";s:2:"en";s:8:"identity";s:16:"admin@gmail.com";s:8:"username";s:16:"admin@gmail.com";s:5:"email";s:16:"admin@gmail";s:7:"user_id";s:1:"2";s:14:"old_last_login";s:10:"1641452323";s:14:"institution_id";s:1:"0";s:20:"employer_category_id";a:0:{}s:13:"user_group_id";s:1:"1";s:13:"employer_name";N;}`

Comment: The formatting doesn't look right to start with, assuming you pulled this from the database, what length is the column set to? Your data looks to be getting truncated or corrupt somewhere.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to repair a serialized string which has been corrupted by an incorrect byte count length?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10152904/how-to-repair-a-serialized-string-which-has-been-corrupted-by-an-incorrect-byte)

Answer (score 0):

The problem most likely lies in some invalid serialization data due to invalid length.

A solution for this would be to recalculate the number of items as well as the length of these items in the serialized data.

```
$recalculated_data = preg_replace_callback( '!s:(\d+):"(.*?)";!', function( $match ) {      
    return ( $match[1] == strlen( $match[2] ) ) ? $match[0] : 's:' . strlen( $match[2] ) . ':"' . $match[2] . '";';
}, $data );

unserialize( $recalculated_data );
```

Also please refrain from using `@` in your code, as this will prevent (important) warnings from showing.

More info on the serialization invalid length: [How to repair a serialized string which has been corrupted by an incorrect byte count length?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10152904/how-to-repair-a-serialized-string-which-has-been-corrupted-by-an-incorrect-byte)